# Exception on Open in OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services, oledbconnection

When I am trying to open a excel into one of my windows service using following code it is throwing "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" on  objConn.Open(); Can any one please help me.

```
         OleDbConnection objConn = null;
        System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
        LogManager LogWrite = new LogManager(); 
        try
        {
            string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Repository\RuleExcel\Rules_Repository_2018-06-28_03-41-29-133.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";
            LogWrite.WriteLog(conn);
            // Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
            objConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
            LogWrite.WriteLog(objConn.DataSource);
            // Open connection with the database.
            objConn.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this below code, it works for me :

```
using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;"""))
                {
                    objConn.Open();

}
```